# Migrating from CRA to Vite, how to Proxy requests as was done in CRA

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vite, http-proxy

In CRA, proxy was a JSON attribute - eg: `"proxy" : "http://localhost:5001"`
This would catch all HTTP requests and forward them to the backend.

Vite has something similar:

```js
export default defineConfig(() => {
        return {
            build: {
                outDir: 'build',
            },
            server: {
                proxy: {
                    "/api":'http://localhost:5001',
                }
            },
            plugins: [react()],
        };
    });
```

The issue is that you have to have a /api prefix on the request for this proxy to work. I cant find any docs discussing a wildcard. Ideally, it would be something like `"/*" : 'http://localhost:5001'` But that doesnt seem to work.

The reason why I don't want /api is we have MANY repos of code for assignments, lecture notes, etc, that all have different `/prefix`es. So one assignment will just have `/todo` and another `/api/trains` etc. We might have to adjust the code so everything is `/api` but hoping for less work.

Ive tried `'/'`, `'/*'`, `'/*/*'`, `'/**'`, `'^.*'`

Comment: The docs specify that [you can use a regex pattern](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy) to match routes. I haven't been able to verify it, but what happens if you make a proxy for a catch all route: `"/^.*": 'https://localhost:5001'`? (I've looked at your section of what you have tried, and I do not see the regex pattern with the leading forward slash, which I think you need to have in there)

Comment: `"/^.*": 'https://localhost:5001'` is a great idea, but still fails. 404 for all API Calls.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, Vite's documentation did not explicitly support wildcards for proxying.

a potential workaround could involve creating a middleware function to handle these requests. Instead of relying solely on Vite's built-in proxy functionality, you might implement custom logic using something like Express (or another appropriate middleware tool) to intercept incoming requests and redirect them to the appropriate backend based on certain conditions.

Here's a conceptual example using Express:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

// Proxy specific routes
app.use('/api', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:5001', changeOrigin: true }));
// Handle other routes as needed
app.use((req, res) => {
  // Your logic to redirect or handle other routes
  // For instance, you might dynamically determine the target based on the incoming request
  // Example:
  if (req.url.startsWith('/todo')) {
    return createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:5002', changeOrigin: true })(req, res);
  }
  // Handle other cases as necessary
});

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: I didnt vet this answer, it may work for someone. We just altered all the URLs to have /api in front of them.